# dataframe.plot exclude missing data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to plot some data over time.
my dataframe has one column`date` with format `2015-11-25 10:00:00` (datetime64) 
the other column, `data`, is format `1.53` (just a series of numbers float64)

Now where it gets tricky, is that the samples were taken in series.
e.g. :

1. 1st series from `2015-11-20 00:00:00` till `2015-11-21 00:00:00`
2. 2nd series from `2015-11-22 00:00:00` till `2015-11-23 00:00:00`
3. 3rd series from `2015-11-24 00:00:00` till `2015-11-25 00:00:00`

All the data is one below the other, so there are no gaps in the data.

so when I execute my code:

```
ax = df.plot(x='Date', y='Data') 
fig = ax.get_figure()
```

I get a graph that fills in the data on the dates that I never measured. 
**All I want is** to show is a graph with the data on the *ACTUAL* dates I measured. I don't understand why python extrapolates these data points. 
How can I turn off this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas' plot() function by default creates a line plot.  If you only want to plot the data points you have, create a scatter plot instead.

```
ax = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='Date', y='Data')
```

See: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#visualization-scatter

---

**Edit**

As pandas' Scatter Plot plotting function requires numeric columns for both x and y axis, you'll run into issues with my original answer.  The best way to do this is to plot using matplotlib directly.  For what you're trying to do, the below sample should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(df['Date'], df['Data'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that. I get a key error 'Date' . Which is very strange. Because why can it plot the graph as a line, but does it give an error as a scatter...?

Comment: Turns out pandas' scatter plot requires numeric columns for the x and y axis.  I suggest you use matplotlib directly instead.  I've updated my answer above.